# "Философия java"

Tags: java

В книге "Философия java" Брюса Эккеля, в теме "Интерфейсы как средство адаптации" есть пример с паттерном "адаптер" для генерации вещественных чисел, не вывода результата в консоль. Прошу помочь в решении проблемы, просто я новичок.

```
 package com.lala.blabla;
 import java.util.Random;
 public interface rand_vals {
 Random rand = new Random (47);
 int random_int = rand.nextInt(10);
 double random_douvle = rand.nextDouble()*10;
 long random_long = rand.nextLong()*10;
 float random_float = rand.nextFloat()*10;}

package com.lala.blabla;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class adapter_random_doubles extends random_doubles implements 
Readable {
private int count;
public adapter_random_doubles(int count)
{this.count = count;}
public int read (CharBuffer rd)
{
    if (count-- == 0)
   return -1;
    String result = Double.toString(next())+" ";
    rd.append(result);
    return result.length();
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new adapter_random_doubles(7));
    if (s.hasNextDouble()){
    System.out.println(s.nextDouble()+" ");}}}


   package com.lala.blabla;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.nio.*;
  public class random_doubles {
  private static Random rand = new Random (47);
  public double next() {return rand.nextDouble();}
  public static void main (String [] args)
   {
    random_doubles rd = new random_doubles();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        System.out.println(rd.next()+" ");
       }}
```

Comment: Укажите в вопросе что должно было быть выведено в консоли и что было выведено. Еще, если вопрос касается только вывода, то не имеющий отношения  к делу код можно убрать.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (s.hasNextDouble()){
    System.out.print(s.nextDouble()+ " ");
}
```

Команда `s.hasNextDouble()` проверяет, является следующее введенное пользователем значение дробным числом. Команда `s.nextDouble()` требует ввести дробное число.

В итоге вы проверяете, ввел ли пользователь дробное число еще до того, как пользователю будет дана такая возможность. Естественно получается false и программа не выполняет этот цикл.

Как решение можно запрашивать строку и проверять, является она дробью или нет:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();
Double d = Double.parseDouble();
while (d != null){
    System.out.print(d+ " ");
    str = s.nextLine();
    d = Double.parseDouble();
}
```

Comment: все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую именно ошибку?

Comment: Добавил строку. Мой пример касался исключительно цикла.